# How to make Movie clip stretch and contract to follow another Movie clip on stage

Tags: actionscript-3, flashdevelop

Hey everyone so I am working on a fishing pole and I created a hook in AS3 that the user controls when they touch the screen the `playerHook` is allowed to move anywhere on the screen in any direction that the user directs it to.

So what i want is for the  `hookLine` to be attached to the hook  and follow it everywhere also the hookLine to be attached to the fishing pole as well, but i want the hook line to of course act like one, in the way that when the user moves the Hook to the end of the screen then the hook line stretches with it and when it is moved back, the hook line contracts. Hope you understand what I'm trying to convey. Just basically how a fishing pole acts.

Here is the code that I am using for the user to control the `playerHook` :

In my Main Function:

```
//Add hook to stage
        playerHook = new mcHook;
        stage.addChild(playerHook);
        playerHook.x = (stage.stageWidth / 2);
        playerHook.y = (stage.stageWidth / 2);

        //Event listeners
        playerHook.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, playerHookMove);
```

In my playerHookMove function:

```
private function playerHookMove(e:Event):void 
    {
        var xCoord = playerHook.x - mouseX;
        var yCoord = playerHook.y - mouseY;


        playerHook.x = playerHook.x - (xCoord / 3.5);
        playerHook.y = playerHook.y - (yCoord / 3.5);
    }
```

If anyone has any idea on how to have the `hookLine` object do what I stated above i would really appreciate it. I have ideas such as scaling and transforming. But not too sure. Please help!

Comment: Why don't you use the drawing api and just draw a line from the pole to hook. In the days pre drawing api, you would use this method http://permadi.com/tutorial/flash4line/index.html but for anything more that a hairline the results look weird..unless you want a strecthed rope looking feel

Comment: If i do this method would i be able to use it with a hittest function. so can i make the api line a separate movie clip? I wanted to code a function that if a object hits the hookLine then you loss a life.

Comment: Maybe something like this?

Comment: You couldn't just hittest the movieclip as it would be a square and your line just a 45 degree diagonal across it. You could do collision detection with a line (drawn with the api) using vector intersections (look up line-versus-point collision)

Comment: try this http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/predicting-collision-points-with-math-in-as3--active-11218. I'm not sure how viable it is cpu wise if you're detecting a lot of objects. I haven't tested flash like that I'm afraid..maybe someone else has or can offer an easier solution

Comment: Well its actually for an android device. Im publishing it on the lastest flash AIR. Alright ill check it out and get back to you thanks

Comment: Actually. What I've suggested is overkill. You could just create a long thin movieclip that is your line and hitTestPoint with the shapeflag parameter set to true. I think with a lot of objects that would tax a mobile's CPU though

Comment: from what you stated earlier i found this but not sure if it would work correctly http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/quickstart/drawing_commands_as3.html

Comment: Yeah but with the drawing api I think you'd need to use vectors to detect a collision

Comment: hmm... Alright well im sure there is something that can be done and save cpu performance. because i need the whole line to have collison detection